# How android app build only phone devices?

Tags: android, cordova

I have just made an android application using cordova which was designed for use with only phone.

This is my AndroidManifest file:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="false" />
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="560" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="420" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="560" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>
```

But Huawei Ascend Mate(https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ascend_mate-5237.php) not supported on google play.

How can I make it so that the application is only available for phone?

Comment: "But Huawei Ascend Mate(https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ascend_mate-5237.php) not supported on google play" -- most likely, that device is categorized as `large`/`hdpi`, and you do not support that combination. "How can I make it so that the application is only available for phone?" -- generally speaking, you don't. "Phone" is a marketing term, not a programming term. For example, the Amazon Kindle Fire 6" is about the same size as that Huawei Ascend Mate. Few would consider this to be a phone, because it lacks telephony capability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: https://catalog.onliner.by/mobile/xiaomi/mimix256b - what combination?